# How do I return a BigInt type from C++ to javascript using N-API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, n-api, node-addon-api

I'm using this https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/bigint.md document as a reference to return a bigint from c++ but I'm getting the following error:

```
error: ‘BigInt’ in namespace ‘Napi’ does not name a type
     Napi::BigInt HelloWrapped(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
```

Here is my source code:

```cpp
#include <napi.h>
#include "bigintexample.h"

std::int64_t bigintexample::hello() {
    return 1234;
}

Napi::BigInt bigintexample::HelloWrapped(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();
    Napi::BigInt returnValue = Napi::BigInt::New(env, bigintexample::hello());

    return returnValue;
}


Napi::Object InitAll(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    exports.Set("hello", Napi::Function::New(env, bigintexample::HelloWrapped));
    return exports;
}


NODE_API_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, InitAll)
```

In napi.h the BigInt feature is only available to if the NAPI_VERSION define is greater than 2147483646. When I set the NAPI_VERSION define to a number higher that 2147483646, I get the following error message

```
/home/user/bigint-napi/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi-inl.h:573:24: error: ‘napi_create_bigint_int64’ was not declared in this scope
   napi_status status = napi_create_bigint_int64(env, val, &value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by add a the define: NAPI_EXPERIMENTAL and removing the NAPI_VERSION define